# Why doesn't my if statement not work in while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have the code set up where if the input is not yes or no print("Type Yes or No") but even if I type yes or no the message is still printed.

```
mylist = []
are_you_done = "no"
while are_you_done != "yes":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    mylist.append(grocery_item)
    if are_you_done != "yes" or are_you_done != "no":
        print("Type Yes or No")
        are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()



for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

Comment: `if are_you_done != "yes" or are_you_done != "no"`— This condition is always true. A string cannot be equal to both "yes" and "no", so it is always unequal to at least one of them.

Comment: @khelwood. Sorry, I'm illiterate. I just realized that you're suggesting swapping or to and, and that's correct of course

Comment: @khelwood You're right. The condition should have "and" instead of "or"

Comment: @MadPhysicis Cool =). I reread it about four times to make sure I hadn't mixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

```
if are_you_done != "yes" or are_you_done != "no":
```

This condition is always true. A string cannot be equal to both "yes" and "no", so it is always unequal to at least one of them.

You mean

```
if are_you_done != "yes" and are_you_done != "no":
```

or

```
if are_you_done not in {"yes", "no"}:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two conditions in your if statement and if *either one* is true, then the question will be printed. In other words, for the question to *not* be printed, then *both* must be true.  In other words, for the question to be skipped, the value in `are_you_done` must be *both* `yes` and `no` at the same time.